# Fixing Packard bell system boot

Tags: boot, bios

Good day Superusers!

I have a Packard bell imedia s2870 computer. It has been working fine,just after a system reboot i got the following error message -

(error: no boot disk or the disk has failed)

I connected the drive to another PC and its working a 100%, i even bought a brand new SSD hard disk and still get the error message.

I did a motherboard reset and its not helping either.

However, when i enter the BIOS and disable (Secure Boot) and enable (Launch CSM) the drives are detected. Now that the original hard drive & SSD drive is being  detected, both drives cannot boot to windows login screen and when i try to boot to windows setup media, the system wont accept any input from the keyboard PS2/USB and Mouse at the Windows installation setup screen.

When Secure boot & CSM are disabled i get the error message:
- (error: no boot disk or the disk has failed)

When Secure boot is (disabled) & Launch CSM (enabled) the drives are detected but no input device functions at the windows setup screen.

1 System BIOS is up to date
2 Hard drives & Input devices working 100%

am i doing something wrong perhaps?